# How To Saved Date In Different Format In View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, razor

Here I am trying to dislay date saved in CommentDate column which datatype is `datetime` in a format `Oct 10, 2017 5:55 PM` for which I have displayed date in view in `@item.CommentDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")` format . 
Now the problem is that as i load page it shows error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments" in view in `ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")` of `@item.CommentDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")`.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `@string.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt}", item.CommentDate)` or use `DateFormatString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")` - is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `CommentDate`, is it a `dynamic`? If so, you need to cast it to a `DateTime` first, as in:

```
@((DateTime)item.CommentDate).ToString("MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will do it all. :-)

```
var d = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt");
```